# merge data from multiple data frames on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, merge

I want to merge multiple dataframes, but only if the keys match and the date range falls within 90 days of the 'InitialAdmit' date range in df1. I want to keep all rows from df1 and only merge additional rows from df2, df3, etc. as long as they match the key and fall within the date range.

Note: Merging the dfs first then accounting for the date range condition didn't work for me. I first used this method, but there were many conditions where the merge was successful but then because the date range is outside the limit, I had the script drop the row. I need to somehow retain all rows from df1.

[Python Pandas: Merging data frames on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283438/python-pandas-merging-data-frames-on-multiple-conditions) - this question is similar but it appears to merge and then apply the conditions. I think the better approach for this is to apply conditions and then merge if conditions are met. Although, I am open to suggestions.

DataFrames:

```
a = {'Key': [100000204, 100000255, 100000271,100000286,100000628], 
 'InitialAdmit': ['2012-06-04', '2012-05-03', '2012-01-16', '2012-10-26', '2012-02-21'],
 '90DayRange': ['2012-09-02', '2012-08-01', '2012-04-15', '2013-01-24', '2012-05-21']
}
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data=a)
df1


b = {'Key': [100000208, 100000255, 100000723,100000286,100000866], 
 'InitialAdmit': ['2012-01-22', '2012-06-03', '2012-10-26', '2012-11-26', '2012-05-11'],
}
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data=b)
df2 

c = {'Key': [100000255, 100000255, 100000702,100000221,100000628], 
 'InitialAdmit': ['2012-06-22', '2012-10-03', '2012-10-26', '2012-11-26', '2012-04-11'],
}
df3 = pandas.DataFrame(data=c)
df3
```

Script:

```
df_NotIncludedRows = pandas.DataFrame()
df_final = pandas.DataFrame()
dfs = [df2] #I plan to add more dataframes so I'm iterating through this list of dfs 

for df in dfs: #iterate through each df in dfs
    for key in df1["Key"]: #iterate through each key found in column 'Id'
        if key in df["Key"]: # find any matching key from df1 in df2 (part of my issue exists here)
            if (df["Admit"] >= df1["InitialAdmit"]) | (df["Admit"] <= df1["90DayRange"]):
                df_final = pandas.merge(df1,df.loc[:],on='Key',how='left') # my df.loc[:] is a little off i think
            else:
                df_NotIncludedRows = df_NotIncludedRows.append(df.loc[:]) # same df.loc[:] issue i believe   
df_NotIncludedRows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still recommend merge then filter , here we using Boolean index and `combine_first`

```
df=df1.merge(df2,on='Key')
m=(df.InitialAdmit_y>=df.InitialAdmit_x)&(df.InitialAdmit_y<=df.InitialAdmit_x)
df1.set_index('Key').combine_first(df[m].set_index('Key'))


Out[215]: 
          90DayRange InitialAdmit InitialAdmit_x InitialAdmit_y
Key                                                            
100000204 2012-09-02   2012-06-04            NaT            NaT
100000255 2012-08-01   2012-05-03     2012-05-03     2012-06-03
100000271 2012-04-15   2012-01-16            NaT            NaT
100000286 2013-01-24   2012-10-26     2012-10-26     2012-11-26
100000628 2012-05-21   2012-02-21            NaT            NaT
```

Comment: Follow up to this approach. This is great and seems to do what I need! So thanks! But some more background which I should have specified: I have about 25 dataframes each with about 500k mil - 3 mil rows. Would the filter then merge approach be more efficient with such large datasets in terms of speed and memory usage?

Comment: @MartyBobak before the merge we do not know  which is the filter , this is why we need merge first , we need find the values' range then filter

Comment: That's fair. If its alright, I want to expand the question with another df, as  I'm finding it difficult to apply your answer on more than two dfs. I used: dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df_merged = reduce(lambda left,right: pandas.merge(left,right,on='Key',how='left'), dfs)  -- to merge multiple dfs, essentially replacing your first line.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `reduce` for the chain merge using a left join. Below demonstrates with 3 copies of *df2*. Also, below assumes *InitialAdmit* is the last column of the dataframe. Reorder as needed.

```
import pandas 
import numpy
from functools import reduce    
...

# LIST OF DATAFRAMES WITH SUFFIXING OF INITIALADMIT TO AVOID NAME COLLISION
dfList = [d.rename(columns={'InitialAdmit':'InitialAdmit_' + str(i)}) 
          for i,d  in enumerate([df1, df2, df2, df2])]

# USER-DEFINED METHOD CONDITIONING ON LAST COLUMN
def mergefilter(x, y):
    tmp = pandas.merge(x, y, on='Key', how='left')
    tmp.loc[~(tmp.iloc[:, -1].between(tmp['InitialAdmit_0'], tmp['90DayRange'])), 
            tmp.columns[-1]] = numpy.nan

    return tmp

finaldf = reduce(mergefilter, dfList)

print(finaldf)
#    90DayRange InitialAdmit_0        Key InitialAdmit_1 InitialAdmit_2 InitialAdmit_3
# 0  2012-09-02     2012-06-04  100000204            NaN            NaN            NaN
# 1  2012-08-01     2012-05-03  100000255     2012-06-03     2012-06-03     2012-06-03
# 2  2012-04-15     2012-01-16  100000271            NaN            NaN            NaN
# 3  2013-01-24     2012-10-26  100000286     2012-11-26     2012-11-26     2012-11-26
# 4  2012-05-21     2012-02-21  100000628            NaN            NaN            NaN
```