# Filling up a column through referencing another dataframe (with dates)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.

The first dataframe contains a column of names, dates, and an empty column on school.

df1:

| Name | Date | School |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 24/06/2015 |  |
| Mary | 15/08/2017 |  |
| Derek | 04/12/2019 |  |

The second dataframe contains a column of names, the schools they've attended, start date and end date

df2:

| Name | Start Date | End Date | School |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 01/01/2011 | 31/06/2014 | Alpha Primary School |
| John | 01/12/2014 | 31/12/2016 | Beta Secondary School |
| Derek | 01/03/2015 | 30/07/2015 | Delta Primary School |
| Derek | 01/08/2015 | 30/09/2018 | Gamma Primary School |
| Derek | 01/01/2019 |  | Mu Seondary School |

I want to fill up the 'school' column in df1, with the school they were attending during the date reflected in the 'date' column. This information will come from df2. However, there are a few quirks in the data to note:

- Some people are still in a particular school as of today. Hence, there is no data under 'end date' in df2 (e.g. Derek in the last row)
- Some people in df1 has no records in df2 (e.g. Mary)
- In some rare instance, some people can be studying in two schools at one particular time. In such scenario, I'll probably just take the data from the first row
- I have 800k rows in df1, and 5 million rows in df2

I've tried the following code:

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
  try:
    df1.at[i, 'School'] = df2[(df2['Name'] == df1['Name'].iloc[i]) & (df2['Start Date'] < df1['Date'].iloc[i]) & ((df2['End Date'] > df1['Date'].iloc[i]) | (df2['End Date'].isnull())).values[0]
  except:
    df1.at[i, 'School'] = ""
```

This code works on a sample of 1,000 row of data. However, it seems extremely convoluted to me, and takes almost 5 hours to run on my full data.

Is there any alternative way to get the results I want in a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid for loop in python for dataframe processing, use inbuilt pandas functions, for your case it looks like below thread approach of using merge and filter is better [link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842009/merge-data-from-multiple-data-frames-on-multiple-conditions)

Also you can refer the article [enter link description here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06) for more details on optimization

Answer (score 1):

Try with `pandas.merge_asof`:

```
df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df2["Start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Start Date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df2["End Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["End Date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")

>>> df1["School"] = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on="Date", right_on="Start Date", by="Name")["School_y"]
```

This just merges on "Start Date" from `df2` but assuming there are no overlapping dates i.e., the same person didn't go to two schools on the same date, this should be enough.